# Natural window resize event invalidating layout in Chrome, forced window resize does not.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/calvintennant/NrJ8T/show/

When I force a window resize by doing: `$(window).resize()` my listener is called, and everything is fine. However if I actually resize the window, I'm getting multiple resize events called within the same frame.

Timeline during forced resize:
[image: timeline]

Timeline during natural resize:
[image: timeline]

Is this a bug in Chrome, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @avram-lavinsky, resize events can be called multiple time per frame.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

Updated example using Request Animation Frame (seen first here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/resize):
http://jsfiddle.net/calvintennant/v69WW/

```
# HTML 
<div class="box-1"></div>
<div class="box-2"></div>
<div class="box-3"></div>

# CSS  
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
.box-1 {
    background: #00F;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.box-2 {
    background: #0F0;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.box-3 {
    background: #F0F;
    height: 66px;
    position: relative;
}

# JS
var box1 = $('.box-1');
var box2 = $('.box-2');
var box3 = $('.box-3');
var drawing = false;
var resizeFired = false;
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;

$(window).resize(function() {
    // set resizedFired to true and execute drawResize if it's not already running
    if (drawing === false) {
        resizeFired = true;
        drawResize();
    }
});

function drawResize() {
    var height;
    // render friendly resize loop
    if (resizeFired === true) {
        resizeFired = false;
        drawing = true;

        height = $(window).height();
        height -= $(box2).height();
        height -= $(box3).height();
        $(box1).height(height);

        requestAnimationFrame(drawResize);
    } else {
        drawing = false;
    }
}
$(window).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Window resize as a user action is real-time event.  It fires many times as the user drags.

Comment: Yep, that's expected. What is unexpected is that it is being called multiple times within the same frame.

Comment: From Google (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline): _A "frame" represents the work the browser must do to render a single frame of content to the display—run JavaScript, handle events, update the DOM and change styles, layout and paint the page._

A frame in the profiler is a segment based on browser tasks.  The event is fired based on user actions.  It makes sense that you could have multiple resize events fire in one frame.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the resize event was naturally throttled to execute no more than once per frame, but it seems that's not the case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/resize